# Cannot Set cookie in axios response

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using the Nuxt.js to develop the website, I want to call API and put the results to the cookie on server side

I will do this part in Nuxt.js middleware.
But I can call API, I can set the cookies, but I CANNOT set cookie using the API response.

Call API

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default ({ res, store }) => {
  if (process.server) {
    axios.get(process.env.tokenAPI)
      .then((response) => {
        const token = response.data.token
        // console.log(token) and the server console will log the result
      })
  }
}
```

SET COOKIE

```
export default ({ res, store }) => {
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [`token=123456`]) // It works!!

}
```

Combine them

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default ({ res, store }) => {
  if (process.server) {
    axios.get(process.env.token)
      .then((response) => {
        const token = response.data.token
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [`token=${token}`]) 
      })
  }
}
```

No cookie is set when I use this code, it should set the cookie from result

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default ({ res, store }) => {
  if (process.server) {
    axios.get(process.env.token)
      .then((response) => {
        document.cookie = "token="+response.data.token+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Server side cannot access document

Answer (score 0):

It's because the middleware has to wait on sending the response until you set the header.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default async ({ res, store }) => {
  if (process.server) {
    const response = await axios.get(process.env.token);
    const token = response.data.token;
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [`token=${token}`]);
  }
}
```